# How do you convert from Townsend Unit $\rm Td$ to $\rm kV/(cm bar)$?

Tags: electromagnetism, si-units, unit-conversion

I have found a conversion online which says 1Td = 2.829 V/(cm Torr) and 1Torr = 0.001332 bar and with this;
1Td = 0.3768 V/(cm bar)

However from literature for SF6;
362Td = 86.3 kV/(cm bar) where they do not show their conversion, The ratio is 1Td = 0.24V/(cm bar)

My conversion has a ratio of 0.3768 whilst literature has 0.24, what am I missing?

Comment: I assume that your calculation is $2.829\ \mbox{V}/(\mbox{cm\, Torr} )= 2.829\ \mbox{V}/(\mbox{cm}\ 0.00133322 \mbox{bar}) = 2121 \ \mbox{V}/(\mbox{cm}\mbox{bar})$. Probably there is something missing to wrong. On Wikipedia I see that the townsed should have units of $\mbox{V}\,\mbox{m}^2$

Comment: Links to the tool you found and the reference which contradicts it would help us decipher what's happening. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

An educated guess by an outsider:

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townsend_(unit)) (whatever weight that holds for you), the townsend has the units of an electric field divided by a number density, which works out to $\rm V\, m^2$.  However, the torr and bar are units of pressure. The ideal gas equation for number density,

$$
n=\frac NV=\frac P{kT}
$$

requires a factor with units of energy ($kT$) to convert between number density and pressure.

In other words, your conversion factor with pressure units depends on the gas temperature.

One way to check this guess of mine would be to compute the assumed temperature in your confusing reference about SF$_6$, and see whether that temperature makes sense given the rest of the paper.